# If one assigns a variable by calling a method, is the method executed every time the variable is used?

Tags: c#

Say I have a method that returns (for example) an integer, like so:

```
int Method()
{
  var result = 1 + 1;
  return result;
}
```

And somewhere else, I call that method as a way to assign  a variable, like so:

```
var first = Method();
var second = first + first;
```

In the second line, is **Method()** called two times? (one for every time *'first'* is mentioned)

Or was **Method()** just called once, its result stored in *'first'*, and that stored result used to compute *'first + first'*?

I am aware this has been asked before, but I didn't find it specifically answered about C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This an example of a question that you can answer on your own by trying the above code. Short answer: No. `Method()` is only called once. You're storing the result it returns.

Comment: Why would C# be any different than other languages? You store the result of a function call in a variable. This is not a reference to the function itself, it's just a copy of its return value.

Comment: More interesting, here it's called twice: `Func<int> first = Method;
            int second = first() + first();`

Comment: @Nasreddine Trying the above code would simply return "4", and with my limited expertise I can't know how many times Method() was called, which IS the scope of the question. I also understand that there ARE specific instances where it is called (n) times. You're basically saying "you should know the answer by knowing the answer".

Comment: @Man: you _can_ know by using a debugger or adding `Console.WriteLine("Method called");` to the `Method`. Maybe you are confusing it with how LINQ sometimes works(keyword "deferred execution") which is a different topic. Here it is a simple assignment of a value to a variable. The variable does not know or store from where the value came.

Comment: @TimSchmelter So you can know the answer by knowing how to figure out the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method is called just once, when you initialize the variable with the function call. It is not called when you are using the variable afterwards.

```
var first = Method();       // Evaluates to 2
var second = first + first; // 2 +2 = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you invoke a method and save the return value and after that using saved return value will not invoke the method again.

In the example you have provided method will be called once

```
var first = Method(); // Method invoked & return value stored to first
var second = first + first; // Now results is summed up instead of method call
```

If you really want to invoke method twice. Don't sum stored value instead invoke method twice manually.

```
var second = Method() + Method();
```

Above snippet will invoke `Method` twice